# TypeScript typecast object Node to object Element

Tags: typescript, casting, element

I am using TypeScript and I have a lot of problems while correctly typing all the variables, especially Node and Element types.

`var pageLst:NodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.aClassName');
 var el:Element = pageLst.item(i) as Element; // gives an TypeScript error TS1005: ';' experted >> after the 'i)' and/or 'as'.`

'pageLst.item(i)' returns a Node, to be seen 'as' Element. The Typescript editor gives no warning. Only on converting the code, the error is generated.

And I thought that also this should work;

`var el:Element = pageLst.item(i);`

Because Element is based on a Node.

Any insights on this problem or just using the < Element >pageLst.item(i) solution.

Comment: Post actual error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that either you're running a fairly old version of the TypeScript compiler (pre-1.8?) or are trying to run the .ts file instead of the .js file.

Comment: tsc -v gives 1.8.10 (the latest version, I understood correctly). 
The error 'TS1005' is given while transcompiling the .ts code.